# Using grunt to concat js for multiple pages

Tags: gruntjs

I'm very new to grunt. As I was reading examples I wondered how should I handle next case. Lets assume I have this structure:

```
    /pages/layout.php
    /pages/index.php
    /pages/contacts.php
```

Layout contains common js (like jquery/bootstrap) while contacts extends layout.php and adds some new js

So, layout uses

```
jquery.js
bootstrap.js
```

contacts.php

```
jquery.js
bootstrap.js
feedback.js
```

In articles I read the authors usually would create only one file, like frontend.js then uglify it. But if I have multiple js-plugins combination for each page, am I right that my concat configuration should look like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // I haven't tested this but that's the way I think it should look
    // Common scripts which will be used on every page
    var layout = ['/path/to/jquery.js', '/path/to/bootstrap.js'];

    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: "\n"
            },

            layout: {
                src: layout.concat(['/path/to/index.js']),
                dest: '/path/to/result'
            },

            contacts: {
                src: layout.concat(['/path/to/feedback.js']),
                dest: '/path/to/result'
            }
        }
     });
}
```

The config might get quite big, depending on how much pages (which use js) I have. Or there is another approach to do such thing?